# I have a list of 1-D arrays. I want to dump it to a csv file with each row as the 1-D array. Is it possible to do it using numpy,save?

Tags: list, csv, numpy, multidimensional-array, dump

Example: f_1= [array([[1.1,2.2,3.7,4.9,5.2 ]], dtype=float32),
 array([[9,11.5,5.8,6.7,8.9]],dtype=float32)]

The dumped file should be csv file with row being the element(1-D array) of the list.

Comment: Check out [ndarray.tofile](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html) which allows you to specify separators etc.

Comment: `np.save(file, np.array(f_1).squeeze())`

Answer (score 0):

Since the two arrays have the same shape, it's easy to make a 2d array, and write that with `savetxt`:

```
In [491]: f_1= [np.array([[1.1,2.2,3.7,4.9,5.2 ]], dtype='float32'), np.array([[9,11.5,5.8,6.7,8.9]],dtype='float32')]

In [492]: f_1
Out[492]: 
[array([[1.1, 2.2, 3.7, 4.9, 5.2]], dtype=float32),
 array([[ 9. , 11.5,  5.8,  6.7,  8.9]], dtype=float32)]
In [493]: x = np.vstack(f_1)
In [494]: x
Out[494]: 
array([[ 1.1,  2.2,  3.7,  4.9,  5.2],
       [ 9. , 11.5,  5.8,  6.7,  8.9]], dtype=float32)
In [495]: x.shape
Out[495]: (2, 5)
In [496]: np.savetxt('test.txt', x,delimiter=',', fmt='%4.1f')
In [497]: cat test.txt
 1.1, 2.2, 3.7, 4.9, 5.2
 9.0,11.5, 5.8, 6.7, 8.9
```